# Syntax error or access violation: 1630 FUNCTION dbparty.DATE_FORMAT does not exist

Tags: mysql, cron, mariadb

i have on my site 7 cron jobs that automatically do commands (y'all know cron purpose but..:)*
but they all throw out the same Error..

this is the cron jobs:

```
*/4 * * * *  /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:bookings:alertImminent >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:bookings:expire >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:bookings:validate >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:bookings:alertExpiring >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
10 */1 * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:bookings:checkBankWires >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
30 17 * * *  /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:currency:update >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
30 2 * * *   /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico_listing_search:computeNotation >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
0 0 27 * *   /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/Symfony/bin/console --env=prod cocorico:listings:alertUpdateCalendars >> /var/www/Alerts/log.log 2>&1
```

Here what's i get in the log..:

```
13:50:02 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "--env=prod cocorico:bookings:alertExpiring". Message: "An exception occurred while executing '

    SELECT  b0_.id AS id_0, b0_.start AS start_1, b0_.end AS end_2,
            b0_.start_time AS start_time_3, b0_.end_time AS end_time_4,
            b0_.status AS status_5, b0_.validated AS validated_6,
            b0_.amount AS amount_7, b0_.amount_fee_as_asker AS amount_fee_as_asker_8,
            b0_.amount_fee_as_offerer AS amount_fee_as_offerer_9,
            b0_.amount_total AS amount_total_10, b0_.cancellation_policy AS cancellation_policy_11,
            b0_.new_booking_at AS new_booking_at_12, b0_.payed_booking_at AS payed_booking_at_13,
            b0_.refused_booking_at AS refused_booking_at_14, b0_.canceled_asker_booking_at AS canceled_asker_booking_at_15,
            b0_.alerted_expiring AS alerted_expiring_16, b0_.alerted_imminent AS alerted_imminent_17,
            b0_.invoice_number AS invoice_number_18, b0_.refund_invoice_number AS refund_invoice_number_19,
            b0_.message AS message_20, b0_.time_zone_asker AS time_zone_asker_21,
            b0_.time_zone_offerer AS time_zone_offerer_22, b0_.mangopay_card_id AS mangopay_card_id_23,
            b0_.mangopay_card_pre_auth_id AS mangopay_card_pre_auth_id_24,
            b0_.mangopay_payin_pre_auth_id AS mangopay_payin_pre_auth_id_25,
            b0_.url_draft AS url_draft_26, b0_.amount_options AS amount_options_27,
            b0_.created_at AS created_at_28, b0_.updated_at AS updated_at_29,
            u1_.username AS username_30, u1_.username_canonical AS username_canonical_31,
            u1_.email AS email_32, u1_.email_canonical AS email_canonical_33,
            u1_.enabled AS enabled_34, u1_.salt AS salt_35, u1_.password AS password_36,
            u1_.last_login AS last_login_37, u1_.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_38,
            u1_.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_39,
            u1_.roles AS roles_40, u1_.id AS id_41, u1_.person_type AS person_type_42,
            u1_.user_type AS user_type_43, u1_.company_name AS company_name_44,
            u1_.last_name AS last_name_45, u1_.first_name AS first_name_46,
            u1_.phone_prefix AS phone_prefix_47, u1_.phone AS phone_48,
            u1_.birthday AS birthday_49, u1_.nationality AS nationality_50,
            u1_.country_of_residence AS country_of_residence_51, u1_.profession AS profession_52,
            u1_.iban AS iban_53, u1_.bic AS bic_54, u1_.bank_owner_name AS bank_owner_name_55,
            u1_.bank_owner_address AS bank_owner_address_56, u1_.annual_income AS annual_income_57,
            u1_.phone_verified AS phone_verified_58, u1_.email_verified AS email_verified_59,
            u1_.id_card_verified AS id_card_verified_60, u1_.nb_bookings_offerer AS nb_bookings_offerer_61, u1_.nb_bookings_asker AS nb_bookings_asker_62, u1_.fee_as_asker AS fee_as_asker_63, u1_.fee_as_offerer AS fee_as_offerer_64, u1_.average_rating_as_asker AS average_rating_as_asker_65, u1_.average_rating_as_offerer AS average_rating_as_offerer_66, u1_.mother_tongue AS mother_tongue_67, u1_.answer_delay AS answer_delay_68, u1_.time_zone AS time_zone_69, u1_.mangopay_id AS mangopay_id_70, u1_.mangopay_wallet_id AS mangopay_wallet_id_71, u1_.mangopay_bank_account_id AS mangopay_bank_account_id_72, u1_.created_at AS created_at_73, u1_.updated_at AS updated_at_74, u1_.slug AS slug_75, u2_.id AS id_76, u2_.facebook_id AS facebook_id_77, u2_.link AS link_78, u2_.last_name AS last_name_79, u2_.first_name AS first_name_80, u2_.birthday AS birthday_81, u2_.address AS address_82, u2_.verified AS verified_83, u2_.location AS location_84, u2_.location_id AS location_id_85, u2_.hometown AS hometown_86, u2_.hometown_id AS hometown_id_87, u2_.gender AS gender_88, u2_.locale AS locale_89, u2_.timezone AS timezone_90, u2_.nb_friends AS nb_friends_91, u2_.picture AS picture_92, u2_.created_at AS created_at_93, u2_.updated_at AS updated_at_94, l3_.id AS id_95, l3_.status AS status_96, l3_.type AS type_97, l3_.price AS price_98, l3_.certified AS certified_99, l3_.min_duration AS min_duration_100, l3_.max_duration AS max_duration_101, l3_.cancellation_policy AS cancellation_policy_102, l3_.average_rating AS average_rating_103, l3_.comment_count AS comment_count_104, l3_.admin_notation AS admin_notation_105, l3_.availabilities_updated_at AS availabilities_updated_at_106, l3_.platform_notation AS platform_notation_107, l3_.created_at AS created_at_108, l3_.updated_at AS updated_at_109, b4_.id AS id_110, b4_.status AS status_111, b4_.amount AS amount_112, b4_.payed_at AS payed_at_113, b4_.mangopay_transfer_id AS mangopay_transfer_id_114, b4_.mangopay_payout_id AS mangopay_payout_id_115, b4_.created_at AS created_at_116, b4_.updated_at AS updated_at_117, b5_.id AS id_118, b5_.status AS status_119, b5_.amount AS amount_120, b5_.payed_at AS payed_at_121, b5_.mangopay_refund_id AS mangopay_refund_id_122, b5_.created_at AS created_at_123, b5_.updated_at AS updated_at_124, m6_.subject AS subject_125, m6_.created_at AS created_at_126, m6_.is_spam AS is_spam_127, m6_.id AS id_128, l7_.title AS title_129, l7_.description AS description_130, l7_.rules AS rules_131, l7_.locale AS locale_132, l7_.id AS id_133, l7_.slug AS slug_134, u8_.username AS username_135, u8_.username_canonical AS username_canonical_136, u8_.email AS email_137, u8_.email_canonical AS email_canonical_138, u8_.enabled AS enabled_139, u8_.salt AS salt_140, u8_.password AS password_141, u8_.last_login AS last_login_142, u8_.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_143, u8_.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_144, u8_.roles AS roles_145, u8_.id AS id_146, u8_.person_type AS person_type_147, u8_.user_type AS user_type_148, u8_.company_name AS company_name_149, u8_.last_name AS last_name_150, u8_.first_name AS first_name_151, u8_.phone_prefix AS phone_prefix_152, u8_.phone AS phone_153, u8_.birthday AS birthday_154, u8_.nationality AS nationality_155, u8_.country_of_residence AS country_of_residence_156, u8_.profession AS profession_157, u8_.iban AS iban_158, u8_.bic AS bic_159, u8_.bank_owner_name AS bank_owner_name_160, u8_.bank_owner_address AS bank_owner_address_161, u8_.annual_income AS annual_income_162, u8_.phone_verified AS phone_verified_163, u8_.email_verified AS email_verified_164, u8_.id_card_verified AS id_card_verified_165, u8_.nb_bookings_offerer AS nb_bookings_offerer_166, u8_.nb_bookings_asker AS nb_bookings_asker_167, u8_.fee_as_asker AS fee_as_asker_168, u8_.fee_as_offerer AS fee_as_offerer_169, u8_.average_rating_as_asker AS average_rating_as_asker_170, u8_.average_rating_as_offerer AS average_rating_as_offerer_171, u8_.mother_tongue AS mother_tongue_172, u8_.answer_delay AS answer_delay_173, u8_.time_zone AS time_zone_174, u8_.mangopay_id AS mangopay_id_175, u8_.mangopay_wallet_id AS mangopay_wallet_id_176, u8_.mangopay_bank_account_id AS mangopay_bank_account_id_177, u8_.created_at AS created_at_178, u8_.updated_at AS updated_at_179, u8_.slug AS slug_180, u9_.id AS id_181, u9_.facebook_id AS facebook_id_182, u9_.link AS link_183, u9_.last_name AS last_name_184, u9_.first_name AS first_name_185, u9_.birthday AS birthday_186, u9_.address AS address_187, u9_.verified AS verified_188, u9_.location AS location_189, u9_.location_id AS location_id_190, u9_.hometown AS hometown_191, u9_.hometown_id AS hometown_id_192, u9_.gender AS gender_193, u9_.locale AS locale_194, u9_.timezone AS timezone_195, u9_.nb_friends AS nb_friends_196, u9_.picture AS picture_197, u9_.created_at AS created_at_198, u9_.updated_at AS updated_at_199, b0_.user_id AS user_id_200, b0_.listing_id AS listing_id_201, u2_.user_id AS user_id_202, l3_.user_id AS user_id_203, l3_.location_id AS location_id_204, b4_.user_id AS user_id_205, b4_.booking_id AS booking_id_206, b5_.user_id AS user_id_207, b5_.booking_id AS booking_id_208, m6_.created_by_id AS created_by_id_209, m6_.listing_id AS listing_id_210, m6_.booking_id AS booking_id_211, l7_.translatable_id AS translatable_id_212, u9_.user_id AS user_id_213
        FROM  booking b0_
        LEFT JOIN  `user` u1_  ON b0_.user_id = u1_.id
        LEFT JOIN  `user_facebook` u2_  ON u1_.id = u2_.user_id
        LEFT JOIN  listing l3_  ON b0_.listing_id = l3_.id
        LEFT JOIN  booking_bank_wire b4_  ON b0_.id = b4_.booking_id
        LEFT JOIN  booking_payin_refund b5_  ON b0_.id = b5_.booking_id
        LEFT JOIN  message_thread m6_  ON b0_.id = m6_.booking_id
        LEFT JOIN  listing_translation l7_  ON l3_.id = l7_.translatable_id
        LEFT JOIN  `user` u8_  ON l3_.user_id = u8_.id
        LEFT JOIN  `user_facebook` u9_  ON u8_.id = u9_.user_id
        WHERE  b0_.status IN (?)
          AND  (b0_.new_booking_at <= ?
                  OR  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT (b0_.start,'%Y-%m-%d'), ' ',
                             DATE_FORMAT (b0_.start_time, '%H:%i:%s')) <= ?
               )
          AND  b0_.alerted_expiring = ?'

 with params [1, "2019-10-02 15:50:02", "2019-10-04 19:50:02", 0]:
```

And :

```
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1630 FUNCTION dbparty.DA
  TE_FORMAT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution'
  section in the Reference Manual


In PDOStatement.php line 144:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1630 FUNCTION dbparty.DA
  TE_FORMAT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution'
  section in the Reference Manual


In PDOStatement.php line 142:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1630 FUNCTION dbparty.DA
  TE_FORMAT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution'
  section in the Reference Manual
```

Comment: IS this DATE_FORMAT not declared in MariadDB ? it seems like this but i can see it at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date_format/

Comment: Yes, the function also exists in MariaDB.
It's a problem with the way MariaDB finds the functions in SQL. It has a setting on the MariaDB server for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the space after the DATE_FORMAT.

From:

```
DATE_FORMAT (b0_.start,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

To:

```
DATE_FORMAT(b0_.start,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html).

> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and
> the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish
> between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen
> to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function
> arguments are permitted.
>
> To tell the MySQL server to accept spaces after function names by
> starting it with the --sql-mode=IGNORE_SPACE option. (See Section
> 7.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”.) Individual client programs can request this behavior by using the CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE option for
> mysql_real_connect(). In either case, all function names become
> reserved words.

Comment: thank you it worked, just removed the space and it all comes OK!

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one SQL, then it is certainly better to remove the space as described by slaakso.

If you are doing a conversion of a very large application from MySQL to MariaDB and you have thousands of SQL's, then it can be difficult and time consuming to fix all these spaces and other details that are in this problem.

MariaDB has a setting that determines how the SQL is scanned for functions:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/

The relevant parameter is: IGNORE_SPACE

My advice is therefore to always save all parameters of the MQL server, regardless of the system. Whether MariaDB, MySQL or another database. If the hosting provider (unintentionally) changes something, I can compare there: What were the parameters before and what parameters does it have now. Even if I can't change the parameters directly on the database server, I can still add the parameter to the SQL and get the app up and running again as quickly as possible.